# Cannot associate app with store

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am using visual studio 2015 and tried to associate my app with the store but the menu in project/store in vs is always disabled. Any ideas? 
I could not find much information while googling and in the tutorials it says that one should choose this option.

Comment: What platform are you targeting when trying to use this menu? It should be enabled for a Windows device target, but disabled for all others.

Comment: Ok. stupid me. Thanks for help. So its only working for Windows. I have to do all other plattform via cordova tools I guess?

Comment: No problem, but yeah right now it only works with Windows. You have to go to other stores directly to handle any deployment/publishing.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling an answer from the comments: The Associate App with Store option only works with Windows projects. So it will appear disabled for other platforms.

Comment: I know you're just posting one of the answers, so don't take this venting as targeting you. This honestly makes no sense to me. I've had nothing but frustration with doing what shouldve been a simple cordova porting of a project to a windows phone. android and ios has been far easier/simpler. it doesn't bode well for the state of windows phone development, definitely making this my last windows phone project we do in my office.